# Haversine formula using SQL server to find closest venue - vb.net

Tags: sql, sql-server, haversine

I am grabbing a postcode from a form. I can then convert this postcode to lng,lat coordinates as I have these stored in a table.

`SELECT lng, lat from postcodeLngLat WHERE postcode = 'CV1'`

I have another table which stores the lng,lat of a selection of venues.

`SELECT v.lat, v.lng, v.name, p.lat, p.lng, p.postcode, 'HAVERSINE' AS distance FROM venuepostcodes v, postcodeLngLat p WHERE p.outcode = 'CB6' ORDER BY distance`

What I am trying to do is create a datagrid which shows the distance of each venue from the postcode (CV1 in this case). I know that the Haversine formula should do what I am trying to achieve but I'm lost as to where I should start incorporating it into my query. I think the formula needs to go where I've put `'HAVERSINE'` in the query above.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

`SELECT o.outcode AS lead_postcode, v.venue_name, 6371.0E * ( 2.0E *asin(case when 1.0E < (sqrt(square(sin(((RADIANS(CAST(o.lat AS FLOAT)))-(RADIANS(CAST(v.lat AS FLOAT))))/2.0E)) + (cos(RADIANS(CAST(v.lat AS FLOAT))) * cos(RADIANS(CAST(o.lat AS FLOAT))) * square(sin(((RADIANS(CAST(o.lng AS FLOAT)))-(RADIANS(CAST(v.lng AS FLOAT))))/2.0E))))) then 1.0E else (sqrt(square(sin(((RADIANS(CAST(o.lat AS FLOAT)))-(RADIANS(CAST(v.lat AS FLOAT))))/2.0E)) + (cos(RADIANS(CAST(v.lat AS FLOAT))) * cos(RADIANS(CAST(o.lat AS FLOAT))) * square(sin(((RADIANS(CAST(o.lng AS FLOAT)))-(RADIANS(CAST(v.lng AS FLOAT))))/2.0E))))) end )) AS distance FROM venuepostcodes v, outcodepostcodes o WHERE o.outcode = 'CB6' ORDER BY distance`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you'd do best putting it in a UDF and using that in your query:

```
SELECT v.lat, v.lng, v.name, p.lat, p.lng, p.postcode, udf_Haversine(v.lat, v.lng, p.lat, p.lng) AS distance FROM venuepostcodes v, postcodeLngLat p WHERE p.outcode = 'CB6' ORDER BY distance

create function dbo.udf_Haversine(@lat1 float, @long1 float, @lat2 float, @long2 float) returns float begin
        declare @dlon float, @dlat float, @rlat1 float, @rlat2 float, @rlong1 float, @rlong2 float, @a float, @c float, @R float, @d float, @DtoR float

        select @DtoR = 0.017453293
        select @R = 3937 --3976

        select 
            @rlat1 = @lat1 * @DtoR,
            @rlong1 = @long1 * @DtoR,
            @rlat2 = @lat2 * @DtoR,
            @rlong2 = @long2 * @DtoR

        select 
            @dlon = @rlong1 - @rlong2,
            @dlat = @rlat1 - @rlat2

        select @a = power(sin(@dlat/2), 2) + cos(@rlat1) * cos(@rlat2) * power(sin(@dlon/2), 2)
        select @c = 2 * atn2(sqrt(@a), sqrt(1-@a))
        select @d = @R * @c

        return @d 
    end
```

Comment: Is it possible to insert this into the .vb file on my .net page or do I need to put the function elsewhere? - plus what is the "float" bit all about?

Comment: the function as written here is a SQL Server user defined function.  You could convert it to vb, but then you would have to bring back all your data to the "client" to do the calculation.  with SQL UDF you can do things like select the top 10 closest and only send data for those 10 to the "client"

Comment: @Tom - I think David is saying to create a function in SQL Server.  UDF -> User Defined Fuction.  (http://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+Server+UDF)

Comment: also, I just noticed the comment in there near @R, might want to verify that the Haversine formula is 100% correct in there.

Comment: OK, so I accept that your idea is certainly the correct way to go about it. I did however recreate this function using the following the code added to my original question... thanks

Comment: Thanks a ton! Saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively uou could also use SQL Server 2008 geography datatypes. If you currently store the longitude/latitide as varchar() in the DB, you will have to store them as geograpghy datatype and then use a function like STIntersects() to get the distance.