# Haversine query into Oracle

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, haversine

I'm currently having to go through my queries and transfer them over to using Oracle rather than SQLSERVER and i'm a bit stuck with this query which i'm using from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362475/haversine-formula-using-sql-server-to-find-closest-venue-vb-net)

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ( SELECT o.outcode AS lead_postcode, v.location, 
v.location_name, v.outcode AS venue_postcode, 6371.0E * 
( 2.0E *asin(case when 1.0E < (sqrt(square(sin(((RADIANS(CAST(o.lat AS FLOAT)))-
(RADIANS(CAST(v.lat AS FLOAT))))/2.0E)) + (cos(RADIANS(CAST(v.lat AS FLOAT))) 
* cos(RADIANS(CAST(o.lat AS FLOAT))) * square(sin(((RADIANS(CAST(o.lng AS FLOAT)))-
(RADIANS(CAST(v.lng AS FLOAT))))/2.0E))))) then 1.0E else 
(sqrt(square(sin(((RADIANS(CAST(o.lat AS FLOAT)))-(RADIANS(CAST(v.lat AS FLOAT))))
/2.0E)) + (cos(RADIANS(CAST(v.lat AS FLOAT))) * cos(RADIANS(CAST(o.lat AS FLOAT)))
* square(sin(((RADIANS(CAST(o.lng AS FLOAT)))-(RADIANS(CAST(v.lng AS FLOAT))))
/2.0E))))) end )) AS distance FROM venue_postcodes v, uk_postcodes o 
WHERE o.outcode = @nrpostcode ) i WHERE distance<100 ORDER BY distance
```

Now I know this is a horrible query to look at but Oracle seems to be having a lot of problems with it.

Firstly it doesn't like the `E` in `6371E` and all the subsequent `E`'s

Secondly it doesn't like the `square` function so I decided to use the `power` function but this still gave me errors.

Thirdly it doesn't like the `radians` function

Fourthly it doesn't like the `TOP 1` part so I had changed this to use `ROWNUM` in the `WHERE` clause

I'm completely lost as to what to do here.

Any ideas as to what I can do to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Transpose from `horrible` to `decent`. Use whitespace. Break into parts (maybe functions). Try every function separately - and find equivalent for Oracle. Try every clause (like `Top`) separately - and find equivalent for Oracle.

Comment: I can't seem to find an alternative to `radians` or work out why the `E` problem is happening though? There doesn't seem to be much on the web with regard to haversine and oracle

Comment: I think if you want to do it "properly", you'd probably be best storing your locations using Oracle's [Spatial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/html/A88805_01/sdo_intr.htm) extension and using one of its distance functions, which I think include Haversine. But I'm no Oracle expert, I'm afraid. Otherwise, drop those "E"s; they're not needed, and start telling us the exact error messages you're getting for each problem.

Comment: @Matt Gibson - I've dropped the `E`'s and the error i'm receiving now is `RADIANS - invalid identifier`

Comment: Oh, and as for radians, just bear in mind that there are 2π radians in a circle, so I reckon you'd just divide the degrees by about 57.3 :) But personally I'd store the latitude and longitude in radians in the database, too, when I added them, to make this bit easier and quicker...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend you take a slightly different approach.

Check out this site: http://psoug.org/reference/functions.html

Look for the part referring to "calc distance"

Comment: I've implemented that into my code and it works a charm - thanks :)

Comment: @Jamie: This is nice and solves the immediate problem of transfering the code to Oracle. When you try any query though with `WHERE distance<100 ORDER BY distance` in big tables, the function has to be calculated for every combination of rows of your two `(venue_postcodes, uk_postcodes)` tables. As suggested by @Matt Gibson, you should use Oracle spatial extensions for medium to big tables, if you want performance to be fast.

Comment: This is a link only answer and the link (currently) appears to be dead.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to do it in SQL Server, which should be easy enough to port over to Oracle:

Here's a UDF I created to get the approximate *crows flight* distance between two zip codes using the Haversine formula:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetZipDistanceMiles](
    @ZipFrom VARCHAR(20),
    @ZipTo VARCHAR(20)
)
RETURNS FLOAT 
AS  
BEGIN 

    DECLARE @Latitude1 FLOAT
    DECLARE @Longitude1 FLOAT
    DECLARE @Latitude2 FLOAT
    DECLARE @Longitude2 FLOAT

    SELECT  @Latitude1 = Latitude,
            @Longitude1 = Longitude
    FROM    ZipCode
    WHERE   ZipCode = @ZipFrom


    SELECT  @Latitude2 = Latitude,
            @Longitude2 = Longitude
    FROM    ZipCode
    WHERE   ZipCode = @ZipTo

    -- CONSTANTS
    DECLARE @EarthRadiusInMiles FLOAT
    SET @EarthRadiusInMiles = 3963.1

    -- RADIANS conversion
    DECLARE @Lat1Radians FLOAT
    DECLARE @Long1Radians FLOAT
    DECLARE @Lat2Radians FLOAT
    DECLARE @Long2Radians FLOAT

    SET @Lat1Radians = @Latitude1 * PI() / 180
    SET @Long1Radians = @Longitude1 * PI() / 180
    SET @Lat2Radians = @Latitude2 * PI() / 180
    SET @Long2Radians = @Longitude2 * PI() / 180

    RETURN ACOS(COS(@Lat1Radians) * COS(@Long1Radians) * COS(@Lat2Radians) * COS(@Long2Radians) + COS(@Lat1Radians) * SIN(@Long1Radians) * COS(@Lat2Radians) * SIN(@Long2Radians) + SIN(@Lat1Radians) * SIN(@Lat2Radians)) * @EarthRadiusInMiles

END
```