# Linq to sql Haversine formula

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have an implementation of the Harversine formula in both c# and an example in TSQL.
I'm unsure how is best to implement the formula on the server side so I'm able to use it within a Linq query.

Ideally, I'd just have my local formula linked to the function on the server. Thus avoiding the "no translation to sql" error and having everything nice and seamless.

Obviously any view on the problem is helpful.

I'm aware of the Geography types in SQL2008. However the code base i'm working against already has such a reliance on Linq to SQL I'd expect It's more effort than it's worth!

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

why not going 100% SQL as it's the best way to make the calculations, and simply get a table already filled up with the distances?

from an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5362942/28004)

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udf_Haversine(@lat1 float, @long1 float, @lat2 float, @long2 float) RETURNS float 
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @dlon float, @dlat float, @rlat1 float, @rlat2 float, @rlong1 float, @rlong2 float, @a float, @c float, @R float, @d float, @DtoR float

    SELECT @DtoR = 0.017453293
    SELECT @R = 3937 --3976

    SELECT 
        @rlat1 = @lat1 * @DtoR,
        @rlong1 = @long1 * @DtoR,
        @rlat2 = @lat2 * @DtoR,
        @rlong2 = @long2 * @DtoR

    SELECT 
        @dlon = @rlong1 - @rlong2,
        @dlat = @rlat1 - @rlat2

    SELECT @a = power(sin(@dlat/2), 2) + cos(@rlat1) * cos(@rlat2) * power(sin(@dlon/2), 2)
    SELECT @c = 2 * atn2(sqrt(@a), sqrt(1-@a))
    SELECT @d = @R * @c

    RETURN @d 
  END
```

and used like:

```cs
var table = from r in db.VenuePostCodes 
            select new {
                lat = r.Latitude,
                lng = r.Longitude,
                name = r.Name,
                distance = db.udf_Haversine(
                                  r.Latitude,r.Longitude,
                                  r.Latitude,r.Longitude2)
            };
```

but the best is always to have everything on SQL so your hosting server has less to do, simply ad a VIEW to your SQL and call that view, let's imagine:

```sql
SELECT 
   latitude, longitude, name, latitude1, longitude2, postcode, 
   udf_Haversine(latitude, longitude, latitude2, longitude2) AS distance 
FROM 
   venuepostcodes
ORDER BY 
   distance
```

and use LINQ to call that view directly.

Comment: I agree that this is the best approach.  It is possible to define the Haversine formula in a LINQ expression, but it will be ugly, and include a lot of redundant calculations (for example, since you can't use expression blocks, you won't be able to store the value of `a`, so you'll have to calculate it twice when computing `c`).  Save yourself the headache, and follow @balexandre's example.

Comment: Cheers, I had already created a function to do it. However I couldn't for the life of me figure out how to call that from within Linq!! Thanks. Will look into using a dedicated view for the geo functionality

Comment: you need to add that SQL function to your Entity first. If you're using `edmx` file, just right click and `Function Import...`

Comment: I'm just using Linq2SQL. Ideally just want to be able to access the udf within the L2S partial entity class. So I can create myFoo.NearestBars() and find all the Bars ordered by distance.

Comment: for pure c# use [this example](http://www.storm-consultancy.com/blog/development/code-snippets/the-haversine-formula-in-c-and-sql/), but it will take take to process, and if not async, it can block the UI... it's always best the SQL Server to do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

@balexandre's answer is great, but I wasn't happy with the SQL function provided (it lacks comments, has the funny commented out constant, is it miles? KM? etc...)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_Haversine](@lat1 float, @long1 float, @lat2 float, @long2 float) RETURNS float 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @dlon float, @dlat float,
            @rlat1 float, @rlat2 float, @rlong1 float, @rlong2 float,
            @a float, @c float, @R float, @d float, @DtoR float

    SELECT
        @DtoR = PI() / 180, -- Degrees to radians const
        @R = 6371 -- Radius of Earth in KM

    SELECT 
        @rlat1 = @lat1 * @DtoR,
        @rlong1 = @long1 * @DtoR,
        @rlat2 = @lat2 * @DtoR,
        @rlong2 = @long2 * @DtoR

    SELECT 
        @dlat = @rlat1 - @rlat2,
        @dlon = @rlong1 - @rlong2

    SELECT @a = SIN(@dlat / 2) * SIN(@dlat / 2) +
                SIN(@dlon / 2) * SIN(@dlon / 2) * COS(@rlat2) * COS(@rlat1)

    SELECT @c = 2 * atn2(sqrt(@a), sqrt(1 - @a))
    SELECT @d = @R * @c -- Final distance in KM

    SELECT @d = @d * 0.621371192 -- Final distance in miles

RETURN @d 
END
```

It's converted from the JavaScript implementation we grabbed from here, with the addition of being converted to miles at the end:

```
// Converted from JavaScript implementation:
// http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c;
```