# C# - LINQ - shortest distance by GPS latitude and longitude

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, gps

I have database and in it I have class hotel with gps coordinates. I want to get closest places to coordinates which I choose.

I think It should look like this (I found many example codes here and like this one):

```
var coord = new GeoCoordinate(latitude, longitude);
var nearest = (from h in db.hotels
               let geo = new GeoCoordinate(h.gps.lat, h.gps.lng)
               orderby geo.GetDistanceTo(coord)
               select h).Take(10);
```

The problem is that I have this error when I tried to search for something:

> Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ
>   to Entities

I tried to google it and I found that dividing that linq into two can help me but I am not sure how. Thanks for help.

Comment: That's currently trying to do the arithmetic *in the database*. I suspect that's not going to work without a lot of work. You quite possibly want a stored proc or a UDF.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the object initializer instead of parameterized constructor:

```
var nearest = (from h in db.hotels
           let geo = new GeoCoordinate{ Latitude = h.gps.lat, Longitude = h.gps.lng}
           orderby geo.GetDistanceTo(coord)
           select h).Take(10);
```

But you will likely have problems caused by the GetDistanceTo method, could you provide the implementation of that method?

Comment: Yea, you're right. You solved my problem with parameterless constructor but I have problem with that method. I am not impelementing that. It's method provided by GeoCoordinate class. As I found else where that I have just few arithmetic operations allow in Linq so I must use them and found some algorithm for that, am I right?

Comment: @Bibo Oh, didn't know GeoCoordinate was a framework class. Linq to Entities constructs an SQL script internally which will later be executed against the database once you for example call a ToList() on an IQueryable<T>, therefore you are right you're limited to the few operations that the SQL data manipulation language allows.

Comment: @Bibo you may find the following two classes helpful: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate.aspx 
GeoDistanceTo implements Haversine formula.

Comment: We can use AsEnumerable()

var nearest = (from h in db.hotels.AsEnumerable()
           let geo = new GeoCoordinate{ Latitude = h.gps.lat, Longitude = h.gps.lng}
           orderby geo.GetDistanceTo(coord)
           select h).ToList();

Comment: @AtifMahmood do you have performance issues with using AsEnumerable?

Comment: @user516883 I have not face any performance issue using AsEnumerable.

Answer (score 6):

I have had a reasonable about of success using this implementation of the [Haversine Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula

```
var startPoint = new { Latitude = 1.123, Longitude = 12.3 };

var closest = entities.Something.OrderBy(x => 12742 * SqlFunctions.Asin(SqlFunctions.SquareRoot(SqlFunctions.Sin(((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (x.Latitude - startPoint.Latitude)) / 2) * SqlFunctions.Sin(((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (x.Latitude - startPoint.Latitude)) / 2) +
                                    SqlFunctions.Cos((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * startPoint.Latitude) * SqlFunctions.Cos((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (x.Latitude)) *
                                    SqlFunctions.Sin(((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (x.Longitude - startPoint.Longitude)) / 2) * SqlFunctions.Sin(((SqlFunctions.Pi() / 180) * (x.Longitude - startPoint.Longitude)) / 2)))).Take(5);
```

Answer (score 4):

I post here my solution which I am using for now. But I choose GwynnBliedd answer because he solves my problem in question.

I added DbGeography type to my class and I am using it instead of saving latitude and longitude in database.

```
locationField = DbGeography.FromText(String.Format("POINT({0} {1})", orig.gps.lat.ToString().Replace(",", "."), orig.gps.lng.ToString().Replace(",", ".")));
```

Then it's very easy to use linq:

```
var coord = DbGeography.FromText(String.Format("POINT({0} {1})", latitude.ToString().Replace(",", "."), longitude.ToString().Replace(",", ".")));
            var nearest = (from h in db.hotels
                           where h.location != null
                           orderby h.location.Distance(coord)
                           select h).Take(limit);
            return nearest;
```

For now this is working solution and it's good. For sometime I would be using this but as few users said here I'll maybe try UDF with implementing Haversine formula (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10919178/367593)).

Comment: +1 - Thanks for the pointer to the DbGeography class!  However: I think you have the order of the longitude and latitude arguments in the FromText method reversed; see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546598/dbgeography-pointfromtext-throws-latitude-values-must-be-between-90-and-90-d