# DbGeography.PointFromText() throws 'Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees' for Japan

Tags: .net, geolocation

Google tells me that Japan's lat/long values are (36,138) but .NET throws the error

`24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I have had the same issue as you, I was using `DbGeography.PointFromText("Point(lat lng)")` when the lat & lng arguments are expected the other way around. The complete answer is this:

```
// From Google, Japan's latitude: 36; longitude: 138
var lat = 36;
var lng = 138;
var location = DbGeography.PointFromText($"Point({lng} {lat})");
```

Comment: This link no longer works. Can you please put whatever content was at the link in your answer rather?

Comment: when I tried to implement the same solution, I couldn't, because PointFromText has 2 parameters. 
public static System.Data.Spatial.DbGeography PointFromText (string pointWellKnownText, int coordinateSystemId);
any Idea?

Comment: I have this solution, but it doesn't work..
 if (geoLocation.Longitude.HasValue && geoLocation.Latitude.HasValue)
            {
                var point = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat,
                                         "POINT({0} {1})", geoLocation.Longitude,
                                         geoLocation.Latitude);


                return DbGeography.PointFromText(point, 4326);
            }