# Can't get a simple Entity Framework spatial query to work

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, spatial-query

This query on my sql server returns lots of rows:

```
declare @referencepoint Geography = Geography::Point(48.208173, 16.373813, 4326);
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE Location.STDistance(@referencepoint) < 20000
```

but the equivalent in EF returns none:

```
DbGeography referencepoint = DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT(48.208173 16.373813)", 4326);
var records = (from r in db.myTable
               where r.Location.Distance(referencepoint ) <= 20000
               select r).ToList();
```

Looking at the query generated via profiler I see this:

```
declare @p3 sys.geography
set @p3=convert(sys.geography,0xE6100000010CD4D17135B25F30408274B169A51A4840)

SELECT *
FROM [myTable]
WHERE ([Location].STDistance(@p3)) <= 20000
```

Does EF have an issue here, or do I?

Comment: It would appear EF does have an issue - PointFromText gets lat & lon reversed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546598/dbgeography-pointfromtext-throws-latitude-values-must-be-between-90-and-90-d

Comment: Or, rather I should say the WellKnownText format used by PointFromText expects Point(lon, lat) whereas TSQL uses Point(lat, lon).  Maybe not an error but certainly confusing...

Answer (score 0):

OP has the issue here :) Both SQL and EF are working as expected. OP's statement was incorrect.

SQL Point Syntax:

```
declare @referencepoint Geography = Geography::Point(48.208173, 16.373813, 4326);
```

is ***actually*** equivalent to .Net:

```
DbGeography referencepoint = DbGeography.PointFromText("POINT(16.373813 48.208173)", 4326);
// Note the parameters are reversed from OP's statement
```

---

In SQL and EF (.Net) the Geography data type uses a standard WellKnownText notation to define points and polygons and other structures internally.

> In [WellKnownText](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wkt-crs) format a Point is specified as POINT(X Y) on a Cartesian plane.
>    - ***Note the lack of a comma, the values are only delimited by a space***

When we want to express the location on the earth as a point on a Cartesian plane, the X axis is the equator, the Y axis is then a [Meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_(geography)) line running between the North and South Poles.

**[Longitute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude)**, by definition is the east-west position on the surface of the Earth (so parallel with the equator, the X ordinate)

**[Latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude)**, by definition is the north-south position on the surface of the Earth (perpendicular to the equator, the Y ordinate)

> Therefore to express a Point on the earth in WellKnownText format as if it were a point on a Cartesian plane we must use this syntax:
>
> **POINT(Longitude Latitude)**

What confuses the issue is that in most verbal and written forms we refer to Latitude and Longitude in that order, so in SQL we have a helper function that takes the parameters in that order, because this was supposed to make it less confusing. And in a way it is, because the parameters are named appropriately. To further explain the point I have expanded out OP's statements with the correction

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @latitude float = 48.208173
DECLARE @longitude float = 16.373813
DECLARE @srid int = 4326
DECLARE @referencepoint Geography = Geography::Point(@latitude, @longitude, @srid);
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE Location.STDistance(@referencepoint) < 20000
```

**.Net**

```
double latitude = 48.208173;
double longitude = 16.373813;
int srid = 4326;
DbGeography referencepoint = DbGeography.PointFromText($"POINT({longitude} {latitude})", srid);
var records = (from r in db.myTable
                where r.Location.Distance(referencepoint) <= 20000
                select r).ToList();
```

---

I can't even find a good reference explaining why we generally refer to Latitude and Longitude (in that order) I suspect it's based on the fact that LatLon rolls off the tongue better or because latitude was discovered/measured first?