# Entity Framework DbGeography is giving me a latitude FormatException error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, geospatial

I'm writing an API that uses Entity Framework 6 to do some GeoSpatial stuff.

I've loaded [zip data](http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/) into a database table where I do a lookup by zip code and get its corresponding latitude and longitude info.

As I was testing different zip codes, I got this error when I looked up and used the lat/long for `90210`

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.FormatException",
  "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeographyValidator.ValidatePoint(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.Validator.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.ForwardingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.CoordinateReversingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParsePointText(Boolean parseParentheses)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.ParseTaggedText(OpenGisType type)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.WellKnownTextReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.ParseText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid)\r\n   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Parse(SqlString s)"
}
```

that lat/long data return from zip lookup is:

```
latitude: "34.0901"
longitude: "-118.4065"
```

Both are returned as strings

When I look up those coordinates in Google maps it does show the correct location (Beverly Hills, CA)

Also the error I'm getting make no sense because `34.0901` is within the `-90 to 90` range.

Here's the relevant code where the issue is happening.  When I created the zip database I removed duplicate zips and made the zip code the key for that table.

```
USZip zipData = context.USZip.Find(zip);
string point = string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", zipData.latitude, zipData.longitude);
var myLocation = DbGeography.FromText(point);
```

Comment: of course after I post this I was able to find a duplicate older question exactly like mine:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546598/dbgeography-pointfromtext-throws-latitude-values-must-be-between-90-and-90-d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the latitude and longitude reversed so the value `118.4065` was seen as the latitude and that falls outside of the -90 to 90 range.

The corrected line should look like this:

```
string point = string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", zipData.longitude, zipData.latitude);
```

Comment: Curious why DBGeography points go against the norm of putting latitude first.  But this works,  thanks!